# web2py CAS custom fields

Tags: single-sign-on, web2py, cas, jasig

I've setup my web2py application to work with JASIG CAS (CAS 2) as follows in db.py:

```
from gluon.contrib.login_methods.cas_auth import CasAuth
auth.settings.login_form=CasAuth(
            urlbase = "https://sso.mysite.co.za",
            actions = ['login','serviceValidate','logout'],
            casversion = 2,
            casusername = "cas:user")
```

My CAS server is configured to pass some custom fields, which I've added as such on the consumer:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']=[Field('tokens')]
```

The problem is that the fields are not being populated. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know how it works in CAS 2, but with CAS 3 and later you have to add the attributes to the attributes repository, take a look at **Static configuration of allowed attributes per sercice** in [CAS Atributes wiki page](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/attributes)

Comment: The attributes are configured on the CAS provider, but they're not being picked up on the CAS consumer (web2py).

Comment: Did you place the  extra fields before the `auth.define_tables(username=True)`?

Comment: Yes @Remco , I can see the fields in the Table, they're just not getting populated.

Comment: Have you checked case sensitivity? 'tokens' vs 'Tokens'  are probably distinct. If you want, you can print a few debug lines in `cas_auth.py` and see what your server provides you with. Search for `dxml = dom.parseString(data)` and start debugging there.

Comment: Thanks @Remco, case is not the issue. I have tried adding debug to catch the incoming XML. Tried adding logging.debug messages, but couldn't find where the debug messages ended up. Any idea on how to turn on / use debugging on web2py?

Comment: @yusufk Sure, check out [the docs](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Logging). Logging can help quit a lot. But you could also log to a private file just for debugging purposes... Or  run the webserver in a debugger (pycharm for example) and set a breakpoint and inspect the running environment.

Comment: Managed to figure it out, forked and submitted a pull request. Code here: https://github.com/yusufk/web2py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were issues on web2py's CAS 2.0 implementation where the XML envelope was inspected but not the actual Attribute structure. I made some changes to a fork and submitted a pull request.

https://github.com/yusufk/web2py